How to resolve ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycairo in Jupyter Lab on MacOSX?
I'm running Mac Ventura 13.3, Python 3.12.1, and I'm trying to create an iPy notebook in Jupyter Lab. More specifically, I'm trying to recreated the code from this tutorial. I have the same preamble and initial code. But I keep getting errors related to pycairo. My current error is running the line
plot(network, vertex_label=vertex_names, vertex_label_size=8,
 edge_arrow_width=1, edge_arrow_size=0.5, autocurve=True, target='myfile.pdf')

I tried adding the line
%pip install pycairo

in a directly above the plot(), because that solution worked previously, but now I'm getting the error ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycairo (a full picture of the output is below). I've looked on several forums, and they all say you fix it by running pip install pycairo, or pip install cairocffi, but neither or working (cairocffi is giving the exact same error as shown). I also tried running the file in VS Code, and I still get the same error... The other questions posted are for different OS or different coding environments, which in many cases doesn't matter, but for some reason for me it is.
I also tried the code
%pip install --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir pycairo

From the pycairo documentation, and that generated the same error.


Most likely you need to install the cairo C library (i.e. not the Python package, but the C library for which the Python package is providing an interface). In addition, you also need pkg-config, which is what your error message is reporting to be missing. For more information, see https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html.

In other words pip doesn't have enough abilities on your sytem to install the additional C library needed. This is a good example of why the Anaconda Distribution or conda may be better to learn and use in the long run. Anaconda/conda has a recipe that would successfully install it, if I recall correctly. (Even if it doesn't, it has more abilities than pip.)
